# How do you undefine existing functions and key maps?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, functions

I am looking at a scenario where in order to keep track of changes to my setup, rather than delete functions and keymaps defined in `vimrc` or other plugin I add commands which disable those functions and keymaps further down the execution sequence.

For example in the example below how would undo the mapping of the `<cr>` key and `undefine` the function like it was never created in the first place?

```
cnoremap <silent> <cr> <cr>:call <SID>CommandCallback()<cr>

function! s:CommandCallback()
  let last_command = @:

  if last_command =~ 'tabnew'
    echomsg "Tabnew was called"
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: I think your best option is to try Tim Pope's [vim-scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) which provides a `:Disarm` function which try to do what you're looking for.

Comment: I'd heartily recommend storing your vim config in source control, which adds many other advantages in addition to making it easy to track changes. ...alternatively, you could always just comment out the parts you no longer want to use!

Answer (score 7):

To remove a command-line mapping, use:

```
:cunmap {lhs}
```

Similar commands exist for the other mapping modes. See `:help :unmap`

To remove a function, use:

```
:delfunction {name}
```