# Remove or Unset a function while vim is running

Tags: functions

I know how to create a function:

```
function Something()
...
endfunction
```

And how to overwrite it:

```
function! Something()
...
endfunction
```

But how to actually remove/unset the function, so it doesn't appear at all when looking at `getcompletion('*', 'function')` output and such?

I also know one can always delete the function from their `.vimrc` or/and just reload vim, but I would prefer to do so without doing that.

Any help/feedback appreciated.

Comment: [How do you undefine existing functions and key maps?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12323)

Comment: Nice! feel free to mark this as duplicate (don't know if i can do it myself) :) @BLayer

Comment: Alright. voted to close this for now. Thanks! @BLayer

Comment: ... No problem!  ...

Comment: Such problems can easily be avoided by never defining global function. Make them script-local or attached to autoload-plugin (still global in that later case, but less annoying where completion is concerned)

Comment: yeah, but this was mainly about a specific thing I wanted to do in my `.vimrc` :) @LucHermitte